# Django-registration-redux adding custom fields to app

Tags: django, django-models

I need to add custom fields to Django-registration-redux such as picture and few other fields. Is there a ref or 2 liner guide for how to do it? As per docs I can call RegistrationView in my app views and import my own created model fields to override it. If this is right approach please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your custom form and then set your registration url to use the custom form.

**Defining your custom form:**

users/form.py

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from users.models import User

class CustomRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'picture', 'password',)
```

**Your main urls file**:

project_name/urls.py

```
from users.forms import CustomRegistrationForm

urlpatterns = [
    [...]

    url(r'^registration/register/$', RegistrationView.as_view(
         form_class=CustomRegistrationForm), name='registration_register',),
    url(r'^registration/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),

    [...]
]
```